# Kotlin for Scala List.combinations() and/or Set.subset()?

Tags: scala, kotlin, collections

What are the Kotlin equivalents for the following Scala collection methods, if they even exist?

- [`List#combinations`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#combinations(n:Int):Iterator[C])
- [`Set#subset`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Set.html#subsets():Iterator[C])

Comment: Are you asking for the equivalent method names in kotlin?

Comment: Yes, if  they exist.

Comment: I don't believe there's anything built in.  There are certainly Java libraries which provide these methods, though.

Answer (score 1):

Scala's [List#combinations](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#combinations(n:Int):Iterator[C]) does the same as [Iterable#windowed](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/windowed.html).

> At the first glance, name *combinations* seems about all possible
>   combinations, but that is about groups of sequenced elements by given
>   size. It named *windowed* in kotlin.

[Set#subset](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Set.html#subsets():Iterator[C]) haven't seen yet in kotlin. May be achieved by extension:

```
fun <E> Set<E>.sets(): Set<Set<E>> = this.fold(mutableSetOf<MutableSet<E>>()) { mSet, currentEl ->
    mset.add(mutableSetOf())
    mset.forEach{ it.add(currentEl) }
}
```